# Is filteredArrayUsingPredicate: an instance method or a class method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm confused about the method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate` and how it works. It seems to be an NSArray method that creates a new array that contains all the objects that satisfy the predicate. I've looked under the class reference for NSArray and it looks to be an instance method.

But if it results in the creation of a new array, why isn't it classified as a class method?

This has thrown my understanding of class and instance methods out the window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've looked under the class reference for `NSArray` and it looks to be an instance method.

That is absolutely right.

> But if it results in the creation of a new array, why isn't it classified as a class method?

Because it needs an instance of `NSArray` to start with. Otherwise, you would end up with a signature like this:

```
[NSArray filteredArray:someArray usingPredicate:somePredicate];
```

Although this signature would be OK too, the current one is perfectly fine. In fact, it is idiomatic for immutable types in Cocoa to return new objects from instance methods. `NSArray` and `NSString` have many such methods.

Mutable classes, on the other hand, often support similar methods that change the instance itself. For example, the counterpart of `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method of `NSArray` would be `filterUsingPredicate:` method of `NSMutableArray`.